# Is it possible to automate data conversion when pulling data from Database with Python?

Tags: python, database, dataframe

I want to automate the data types (varchar, int etc.) in the database as soon as the data is taken. I don't want it to detect type like "object" when processing DataFrame.

Comment: You can use object serialization tool like marshmallow.

Comment: write function which gets data and converts types and later use this function everytime when you get data from DataBase.